# Name of a component that shows a hierarchy

Tags: website-design, component

Does anybody know if this component has a name?

[image]

I think the design was very popular for breadcrumbs on the past, but in this case the options do not dissapear as we navigate backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks more like a **progress tracker** or a progress indicator.

Smashing Magazine: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/progress-trackers-in-web-design-examples-and-best-design-practices/

UXPlanet : https://uxplanet.org/progress-trackers-in-ux-design-4319cef1c600

Progress tracker displays all the states including the final state. This creates a clear path to completion.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a stepper or wizard.

In google material design:

https://material-ui.com/demos/steppers/

https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview